# Locust - Authentication with GCP Metadata Server

Tags: python, locust

Trying to write a simple load test with locust.

I just a have a single api which calls an endpoint get some data. The endpoint requires some credentials, lets say Http Basic auth.

I'm running this program in a GCP VM or GKE machine with the pods/machine has required permissions to access GCP Secret Manager (where I stored my credentials).

While running the program directly with python3 auth.py everything works fine and code is automatically getting authenticated with GCP and Metadata server.

But when the same program runs through locust, it's not getting authenticated and fails with error.

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
        details = "Deadline Exceeded"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Deadline Exceeded {created_time:"2023-03-26T08:07:28.371600607+00:00", grpc_status:4}"
```

```
# Import the Secret Manager client library.
from google.cloud import secretmanager

# GCP project in which to store secrets in Secret Manager.
project_id = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"

# ID of the secret to create.
secret_id = "YOUR_SECRET_ID"

# Create the Secret Manager client.
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

# Build the parent name from the project.
parent = f"projects/{project_id}"

# Create the parent secret.
secret = client.create_secret(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "secret_id": secret_id,
        "secret": {"replication": {"automatic": {}}},
    }
)

# Add the secret version.
version = client.add_secret_version(
    request={"parent": secret.name, "payload": {"data": b"hello world!"}}
)

# Access the secret version.
response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": version.name})

# Print the secret payload.
#
# WARNING: Do not print the secret in a production environment - this
# snippet is showing how to access the secret material.
payload = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
print("Plaintext: {}".format(payload))
```

Example : https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

Additional Note: If I use service-account.json this is working fine.

Not sure why it's not working natively, I'm suspecting the child threads or leaflets not able to access machine context ?

Comment: Did you run `grpc_gevent.init_gevent()`as suggested here? https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html#grpc

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this kind of thing happens when the library you're using isn't [gevent compatible](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html#testing-other-systems-protocols). If it's not, you can find another library that does the same thing that is gevent compatible, you can try [monkey patching](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching) the library to make it compatible, or you can write your own replacement functions that call the APIs directly and that should be fine for gevent.